# XSL variable number of child nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've got some XML elements with a number attached as more are available.

Such as this:

```
<Images>
    <Image1>C:\Path\To\AnImage</Image1>

    <Image2>C:\Path\To\AnotherImage</Image2>
</Images>
```

The amount of Images in each XML doc is variable.  How can I make sure that my XSL file will show all elements inside the  tag?

I also want to put each of the strings inside each ImageX tag inside a Img src="stringfromxmlelement" with XSL?  Is this possible?

Tony

Comment: I would only warn that using local disk file system paths instead of URL's to display images is only going to work if both the client and the server runs at the **same** machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Images/*[starts-with(name(),'Image']">
<img src="{.}" />
</xsl:template>
```

BTW, perhaps you can't change the XML tag names, but it would better to name the inner tags as Image rather than ImageX, which is probably unneccesary.

Comment: Agreed about the tag names - if there is a need to distinguish between them or to sort then one should add an appropriate attribute

Comment: What's `</>`? I'm quite sure this is illegal.

Comment: It's just a quick (illegal) way to type a closing tag. The xsl:template tag would need to be properly closed.

Comment: BTW, it's also a (legal) shortcut in SGML, which is the father of XML. Sometimes I wish XML had adopted the notation. :-)

Comment: Legalised ... newbies might get confused

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="Images">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <img src="{text()}" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```